# Court literature- What does this sentence mean

Tags: understanding

The court reserves jurisdiction to allocate the guardian ad litem incurred as the previously appointed guardian at litem is no longer available

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you don't understand? Tenses? The use of "as"? Something else?

Comment: Please quote the surrounding text exactly (copy and paste, don't re-type).

Comment: Or is it the Latin phrase "ad litem" you don't understand? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ad-litem

Comment: This seems unlikely to be an "English Learning" question. Court literature isn't commonly used for the study of English.  You may want to ask on [Law.se]. But you would certainly need to give more detail, and note that they don't offer legal advice in specific cases, only general education about legal matters.

Comment: The use of "incur" is not the standard English use (generally, expenses or damage are incurred), but may be more common in legal documents. Is that your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence appears to mean

> The court reserves the right to appoint a new guardian [to act on
> behalf of X] since the previous guardian they appointed is no longer
> available.

Or more simply

> The court will appoint a new guardian as the previous one isn't
> available.

Comment: It's not saying the court will, but the court asserts that it has the right to.